# How to refresh Data Grid view from other form in c# without reopening?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a main MDI form with two forms inside. One is EmployeeAdd and other is EmployeeView. 
    There is a button on EmployeeAdd to save inserted data in database. and in EmployeeView, there is a Data Grid to view data from database. the problem is i want to update data grid imediately without reopening the main form. here is code of my save button of EmployeeAdd form.

```
        try
       {
        con.ConnectionString = constr;
        con.Open();
        OleDbCommand comnd = new OleDbCommand();
        comnd.Connection = con;
        comnd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO employees([EmpName],[EmpF_Name],[CNIC],[DOB],MobileNo,OtherNo,DOJ,EmpAddress,RefName,RefMobile,RefOtherNo,RefAddress) VALUES('"
        + txtEmpName.Text + "','" + txtFName.Text + "','" + mTxtCNIC.Text + "','" + mTxtDOB.Text
        + "','" + mTxtMobile.Text + "','" + txtOther.Text + "','" + dateTimePicker1.Text + "','" + txtAddress.Text
        + "','" + txtRefName.Text + "','" + mTxtRefMobile.Text + "','" + txtRefOther.Text + "','" + txtRefAddress.Text + "')";
        OleDbDataReader reader = comnd.ExecuteReader();
        MessageBox.Show("Record has been saved successfully", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);}            catch (Exception ex)
      {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
      }
        con.Close();
```

Comment: Have you tried saving the reference to the employee view form in a variable and then passing it (as a parameter/local attribute/static variable depending on your code) so you can access that reference on your button?

Comment: no, I did not.can u explain it by code?

Comment: It depends on whether your first form is called inside or outside your second, therefore my previous comment, so at least the code for your two forms would be necessary for such an answer.

Comment: let me explain... there is a Main form.where all forms are present and it is a mdi form. then there is a menu bar where is EmployeeAdd and ExployeeView. both are present in Main form

Comment: then you can save a reference for both childs (View and Add) as attributes and call the main form through the MdiParent accessor and then update the view

Comment: can u please explain your answer by code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

basically what you need is to write a method that loads all records from DB, then when ever you add an employee clear the data grid view and reload.